# jQuery Masonry update columnwidth at different breakpoints

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, jquery-masonry

I am using jQuery Masonry and I'm trying to update the column width depending on the window width. I have this working without any issues with the simple boolean:

`columnWidth: $(document).width() > 1280 ? 380 : 260`

I've tried several different ways of writing an `else if` type of statement so that I can configure different values at multiple (3+) breakpoints, but I keep coming up short. I tried the following, but it did not work:

```
var colWidth;
if ($(window).width() <= 599) { colWidth = 180; } 
else if ($(window).width() >= 600) { colWidth = 240; }
else if ($(window).width() >= 1280) { colWidth = 380; }
```

`columnWidth: colWidth,`

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

One working, but not nice solution is to recreate the masonry, if needed:

```
function getColWidth() {
    return (window.innerWidth <= 500) ? 62 : 75;
}

window.onresize = attemptSetColWidth;

var prevWidth = getColWidth();
function setColWidth() {
    if(prevWidth == getColWidth()) return;
    $container.masonry('destroy');
    $container = $('.productContainer').masonry({
        columnWidth: getColWidth(),
        gutter: 10,
    });
    $container.masonry('reloadItems');
    prevWidth = getColWidth();
}

var timeOutId;
function attemptSetColWidth() {
    clearTimeout(timeOutId);
    timeOutId = setTimeout(setColWidth, 500);
}
```